# Android - get selection of text from EditText

Tags: android, selection, android-edittext

I'm trying to implement a copy/paste function. How can I get a selection of text from an EditText?

```
EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.title);
```

blabla onclicklistener on a button:

```
int startSelection=et.getSelectionStart();
int endSelection=et.getSelectionEnd();
```

Then I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16):

Seems like you've already done the hard part by finding what the selected area is.  Now you just need to pull that substring out of the full text.

Try this:

```
String selectedText = et.getText().substring(startSelection, endSelection);
```

It's just a basic [Java String](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) operation.

Comment: A minor gripe with android is that getSelectionStart() and getSelectionEnd() refers to the order in which stuff was selected, which doesn't necessarily lead to Start < End... (not a big deal here, but nice to remember, saves a few OutOfBounds')

Comment: Guys, i'm doing like your answer, but my getselectionStart() and getSelectionEnd() method are with problems. Both are returning the same value.

Comment: et.getText() returns an editable. substring() nees a String. You need to add toString(). That is - et.getText().toString().substring(start, end)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a special function from the Editable object:

```
Editable txt = et.getText();
txt.replace(int st, int en, CharSequence source)
```

This command replaces the part specified with (st..en) with the String (CharSequence).

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to do all this, just long press on edit text it will show you all relevant options to Copy/Paste/Select etc. If you want to save the text use the method shown by mbaird

Answer (score 0):

String selectedText = et.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);
getText() returns an editable. substring needs a String. toString() connects them properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way to get the selected text from `EditText`:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
int min = 0;
int max = editText.getText().length();
if (editText.isFocused()) {
    final int selStart = editText.getSelectionStart();
    final int selEnd = editText.getSelectionEnd();
    min = Math.max(0, Math.min(selStart, selEnd));
    max = Math.max(0, Math.max(selStart, selEnd));
}
// here is your selected text
final CharSequence selectedText = editText.getText().subSequence(min, max);
String text = selectedText.toString();
```