# How I can determine which text is selected in EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-widget

Is possible to determine if user selected some text in EditText? If yes, is possible to determine which text? How?

I am programming something like text editor and i need set some text as header when user select it and click on button which is under edit text

thx for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
int startSelection=et.getSelectionStart();
int endSelection=et.getSelectionEnd();
String selectedText = et.getText().substring(startSelection, endSelection);
```

See this question:
[Android - get selection of text from EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163017/android-get-selection-of-text-from-edittext)

Comment: exits something like onSelectionListener? I want to show the button if user is selecting or just selected

Comment: I think I overread your basic question, I am sorry. Yeah, I am no Android programmer, but I think there might be something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188392/text-selection-listener-in-androidapi-level-7